# Excel 2016 crashes on open excel file when I try to edit any cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to help a friend who uses Excel 2016.  After leaving his Windows 10 pc one morning for a few hours, he can no longer edit an Excel file without Excel crashing.  As soon as he tries to edit an existing or new file, Excel crashes.  I loaded an old version of 2003 Pro and Excel works fine on all files opened on the same PC.  I also noticed that Excel tries to show autorecovery on 1 or 2 files everytime the 2016 version is opened.  We have done the Repair.  We have uninstalled and re-installed 2016.  Any ideas now?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

answers:

1. The "crash" comes up to a wait, close, or continue frame
2. You can open any excel file without issue.

Comment: What kind of a crash?

Comment: And can you open those 1 or 2 files on another machine with no issues?

Comment: The "crash" comes up to a wait, close, or continue frame
You can open any excel file without issue.

Comment: Try to open in safe mode and test again, maybe install any add-ins. Open it in safe mode running the following command: Press Win + R, type "excel /safe" in the blank box, press Enter. If it works fine in safe mode, please check the add-ins in your excel and disable them.

Comment: Also try disabling Hardware Graphics Acceleration. Excel ->File -> Options ->Advanced ->Display.